# How to call a method with arguments of different types using reflection in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to call a function that takes two parameters (a boolean and a string) using .NET reflection in C#. However, with the following code i get an exception:

```
object[] paramList = new object[] { true, "Foo" };

Type wsType = typeof(MyWS);
MyWS inst = (MyWS)Activator.CreateInstance(wsType);
MethodInfo method = wsType.GetMethod(function);    // function = the name of the function to be called
method.Invoke(inst, paramList);
```

This throws an ArrayTypeMismatchException ("Attempted to access an element as a type incompatible with the array.").

It seems that paramList is causing the exception, but I have no idea why?

The function I'm trying to call would be something like:

```
public bool EnableSchedule(bool enable, string password)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Check that the `function` variable really contains the name of the function which accepts these two parameters. Apart from that, your code should work.

Comment: An array *can* contain elements of different types, especially an object array.  Document your question better, show the type and method you're trying to invoke and the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Unless you provide the definition (or declaration at least) of "function", its hand to figure what is going wrong. Incorrect order of parameters? Is it possible your function receives (string, bool) and not (bool, string)?

Comment: Try adding the line `function = "EnableSchedule";` below the `paramList` and run it again. And as @Hans said, stack trace will show you where the problem is (I bet you are just calling the wrong function).

Comment: the code executes with no problem if method body is like "return true;". maybe the method is throwing exception not this code you pasted

Comment: Code works fine, as @wiero said. Check it here: http://ideone.com/drI1v. Output of the test app is `"Returned: true"`, no exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem like there is anything wrong with what you are doing - unless the problem lies in the "MyWS". I assume the class is public.
Meanwhile, try adding some binding flags to GetMethod(), like

```
wsType.GetMethod(function, BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
```